# Why I got "advice has not been applied" warning?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, ajdt

Why does the following code:

```
 pointcut callsToList() : call(* List.*(..));

 before(List l) : callsToList() && target(l) {
  System.out.println("cool");
 }
```

generates the following warning:

> advice defined in
>   org.eclipse.ajdt.examples.ListAdvice
>   has not been applied
>   [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

I am working with in Eclipse. I installed [eclipse aspectj plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and of course my project is an aspectj project.

Edit: Moreover I started from a working example provided by ajdt plugin:

```
pointcut callsToBeginTask() : call(void IProgressMonitor.beginTask(..)); 
before() : callsToBeginTask() {
     System.out.println("cool");
};
```

I can't see any difference except the fact that this example works without warning ...

Comment: Maybe this is related to Eclipse/OSgi class loading policy ? How does aspectj work in order to hook the provided pointcuts ?

Comment: Can you show the code that should be weaved by the advice?

Comment: Not sure to understand your request. I want this advice to be called in an Eclipse application running several custom plugins. Thus the code I want to "analyze" is splitted across many plugins/packages/classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want AspectJ to work in an OSGi environment, you must use Equinox Aspects (aka Equinox Weaving).  This is a form of Load time weaving that works with osgi classloaders.

This tutorial is a little out of date, but should get you started:

http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php

When your aspects are all targeted within the same project, you do not need Equinox Aspects.  Regular compile time weaving will do, but to span multiple bundles/plugins, this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that because List is an interface and you want to match calls to all extending Classes you would have to use this syntax:

```
pointcut callsToList() : call(* List+.*(..));
```

Update: OK, I got it to work with this version:

```
pointcut callsToList(List list) :
    call(* java.util.List+.*(..)) && target(list);

Object around(List l) : callsToList(l) {
    // code here
}
```

This also works:

```
before(List l) : callsToList(l) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve my issue. Moreover I started from a working example provided by ajdt plugin:  pointcut callsToBeginTask() : call(void IProgressMonitor.beginTask(..));
 
 before() : callsToBeginTask() {};

Comment: This example doesn't generate any warning even if IProgressMonitor is an interface.

Comment: see my updated answer, this works for me. about the progressmonitor stuff: please put that in your question (or a separate question) if you want it answered.

Comment: So I guess you reproduced the same Issue than me ? Have you got an idea about why we need using around ?? According to the doc of aspectj it should work with before, isn't it ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I had all kinds of strange issues, but now it works, with before as well (see my update)